# upload file to Blob through Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am working on application that is connected to a Blob Database and I am having an exception being thrown whenever I try to pick a file from my PC and upload it. This is the code:

```
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("filep2pstorage", connectionString);
CloudStorageAccount sotrageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, false);
CloudBlobClient _client = sotrageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = _client.GetContainerReference("filep2pshare");
container.CreateIfNotExists();

OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

dialog.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
dialog.FilterIndex = 1;
dialog.Multiselect = true;

string filename = dialog.FileName;                 
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

dialog.InitialDirectory = path;
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path + filename))
    {
        blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Basically, this line of code here:

```
 CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

 using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path + filename))
 {
      blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
 }
```

Does not take the file name. I was breakpointing and the filename is just set to "".

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the following line of code inside the if.  It is not set in the dialog when you get it at the current location.

```
string filename = dialog.FileName;
```